# Primefaces push without maven?

Tags: primefaces

This is my situation:

I have a JSF/PRIMEFACES web application thats currently taking shape in netbean and I need to notify users of the app of few things as they happen on the site so I've decided to use primefaces push for the notification work.

However, I am less than a year into java/JSF and currently don't know how to use maven(holding my hands to my face) which is required to define primefacespush dependency

I've remotely installed maven and pointed to it path from netbean like this: **

> netbean>>tool>>option>>java>>maven>>maven Home>>C:\apache-maven-3.3.9

**, but I don't exactly know where or what to do from here.

would anyone mind pointing me to recent PFP tutorial I could follow? (all else I've seen expect one to have been familiar with maven) or maybe give me a grounding tutorial right here. i'll appreciate it.

I'm also not sure what the right question to be asking is and I won't mind someone telling me what I should be looking to ask.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces Push does not require Maven, it knows nothing about whatever dependency management tool you use or if you do it manually. It **does** require some dependent libraries to be present to function. PFP is directly dependent on Atmosphere (version 2.4.6 for PF 6.1 as can be seen in the documentation). Atmosphere might in turn be dependent on additional libraries as well. This 'dependency management' is what Maven and other similar tools (Ivy, Gradle, ... ) solve for you. So you better ask a new question, tagged 'netbeans, maven' and learn about that part.